# Allow user to yellow highlight webview text in android

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I have `webview` to show some pages to users:

for example:

```
case "page1":
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page1.html");
    break;
case "page2":
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page2.html");
    break;
```

The pages has texts. I'd like to allow user to highlight in yellow parts of it and, if possible, I'd these pages to remember the texts highlights for the next time the user runs the app.

Any ideas if it is possible and how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

By uploading html files using JSOUP, you can color the related text contents according to the user's choice. You can record the colored parts regionally and then show them to the user by recalling them.

[For Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411362/highlighting-using-regex-in-jsoup-for-android)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for your answer. I'll check.